# Why does `MemoryInUse` keep increasing?

Tags: performance-tuning, notebooks, memory

Consider `MemoryInUse`. After kernel initiation, I have noticed that its value keeps increasing, even when not evaluating any cell, as seen

```
ml = Table[MemoryInUse[], {t, 0, 10000}];
ListPlot[ml, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {Mean@ml - 100000, Mean@ml + 100000}}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Any idea why this happens? Where could I read more about memory management within Mathematica notebooks? Any way to reset it?

**Edit:** Also, I have noticed that by re-evaluating a cell with the code `MemoryInUse[]`, the value increases every time I evaluate it.

Comment: One could argue that the "edit" is not a clarification of the problem but [moving the goalpost](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1808/10397). The `MemoryInUse` keeps increasing every time you do something that uses new memory. Among other things , the  *Session History* or lingering variables.

Answer (score 4):

## Explanation

At least on my system,  the slope `Mean@Differences@ml` is equal to $16$
bytes, which is equal to `ByteCount[MemoryInUse[]]`.

It looks like the [`MemoryInUse`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MemoryInUse.html) increases exactly by the [`ByteCount`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ByteCount.html) amount it takes to store the output of `MemoryInUse`, as the [`Table`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) executes and stores each value.

I don't find that surprising at all, as you fill the table with data that is stored in memory, that increases the memory used.

## Solution

To understand this better, unsurprisingly, the best option would be to read the documentation about [Memory Management](https://reference.wolframcloud.com/cloudplatform/tutorial/GlobalAspectsOfWolframSystemSessions.html#15717). It's unclear what you mean with "Reset" the memory in use, but if yu mean minimizing the amount of `MemoryInUse[]` could be a question on its own.

If you want to avoid that increase during the table execution, you will need to either pre-allocate the data in memory or not use memory at all, by writing on disk.

### Pre-allocation

You can pre-allocate the `Table` and update its content like this

```
ml = ConstantArray[0,10000];
Do[ ml[[t]]=MemoryInUse[], {t, 10000}];
```

[image]

### Write to disk

Alternatively, you could store the values on disk instead of memory.

```
Block[
    {
        fname = FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "testfile"}],
        s
    },
    s = OpenWrite[fname];
    Do[ Write[s, MemoryInUse[] ], 1000];
    Close[fname];
    ListPlot[ ReadList[fname] ]
]
```

[image]

Comment: That makes sense. However, without the `Table` object, by simply re-evaluating a cell with the line `MemoryInUse[]`, I get an increasing value every time.  Do you get this as well? What causes this? I have added this comment as an edit to the original question. By reset, I meant minimising this change. I am not too familiar with memory usage within Mathematica, but happy to read more about it.

Comment: Are you leaving the results in the stack? Try `$HistoryLength = 0`. `$HistoryLength` *specifies the number of previous lines of input and output to keep in a Wolfram System session.* Can't test any further without detailed explanation of what you are doing and what is the observation.

Comment: @samwolfe You are not just re-evaluating it. In order to collect the result, values have to be stored somewhere. So, every item allocates another block of memory...

Comment: @samwolfe If you want to see something not accumulating memory usage on the kernel side on every evaluation, look at `Do[Echo[MemoryInUse[]], 100]`. That doesn't append entries to a list.

Comment: @kirma not on the *kernel*, but will use memory on the *front end*.

Comment: @rhermans Yes, I tried to imply that. ;)

Comment: @rhermans Yes I have used `$HistoryLength = 0`, but I see the number still going up. I understand @kirma's answer, but I was wondering if it is possible to avoid this accumulation from single evaluations, separate, evaluations.

Comment: @samwolfe, I suggest you first read the [other questions about `MemoryInUse`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=MemoryInUse) and then ask a new question specifically about your reproducible experiment, with code and detailed explanation, acknowledging the other questions and explaining why those do not answer your question.